# Skrollr Body is not tall enough to show all content

Tags: javascript, css, skrollr

Assuming window height is 768px and content height be 1080px and
:

when I scroll to bottom, since winHeight < contentHeight, part of content is not shown. What can I do for this?

[image]

Comment: overflow: scroll https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: please provide the code (html,css)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on one of my pages.  Since overflow is set to `overflow: hidden` from the tutorial I was following I had to set `overflow: visible` for a couple specific sections so that all of the content would be visible.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Luw54j8x/

There is probably a bit of extra code in the CSS/js, but the important thing to pay attention to is the last few lines of the CSS.  Remove the comment tags to see all of the content visible after scrolling.

Comment: May you show me the demo with Plunker or JSFiddle? Thank you for replying

Comment: Sure thing. Added it to the answer.